# Почему-то выходит None в конце. Вместо return писал print(), но ошибку выдает. (Python)

Tags: python

Надо написать функцию `sequence(n)`, которая будет распечатывать последовательность чисел без использования цикла `for` / `while`.

Если задано число **`n`**, выведите следующий последовательность чисел без использования цикла.

Мы уменьшаем число **`n`** на **`5`**, пока не достигнем отрицательного числа или **`0`**.

```
list_of_numbers=[]

def sequence(n):
    list_of_numbers.append(n)
    if n<=0:
        print(list_of_numbers)
        return list_of_numbers.clear()
    return sequence(n-5)

print(sequence(16))

[16, 11, 6, 1, -4]
None
```

Comment: Метод `clear` у списков ничего не возвращает, а значит `return list_of_numbers.clear()` возвращает тоже ничего, то есть `None`, а так как вы печатаете возвращаемое значение функции `sequence`, то этот самый `None` и отпечатался

Comment: @andreymal а не в курсе как это исправить? либо как правильно написать код на данную задачу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас же внешний вызов уже делает печать, зачем вам печатать два раза - внутри функции и снаружи? Вместо:

```
        print(list_of_numbers)
        return list_of_numbers.clear()
```

Просто верните список, и он напечатается снаружи функции, вместо `None`:

```
        return list_of_numbers
```

А если вам нужно переиспользовать функцию, а значит всё же очищать как-то список, то определяйте пустой список внутри функции, а не снаружи, с помощью аргумента по умолчанию `None`, а при рекурсивном вызове передавайте список в функцию в явном виде. В результате получится такой код:

```
def sequence(n, list_of_numbers=None):
    if list_of_numbers is None:
        list_of_numbers=[]
    list_of_numbers.append(n)
    if n<=0:
        return list_of_numbers
    return sequence(n-5, list_of_numbers)

print(sequence(16))
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, заработало). Не додумался до этого)