# Помогите пожалуйста решить задачу по Python

Tags: python

Помогите пожалуйста написать функцию sequence(n), которая будет распечатывать последовательность чисел без использования цикла for / while. Если задано число n, нужно вывести последовательность чисел без использования цикла. Мы уменьшаем число n на 5, пока не достигнем отрицательного числа или 0.

Не могу понять куда поставить list_of_numbers=[]. Из-за того, что там где сейчас он стоит у меня не получается добавлять новые значения n в список list_of_numbers. В ответе только печатается список из последних значений. Например при n=16 ответ получается n=[-4], а не [16, 11, 6, 1, -4]. Если выносить снаружи функции def, то при последующем использовании другого значения n, список добавляет новые значения к уже существующим ранее значениям. Также по условиям задачи в функции sequence(n) должен быть только один входной аргумент, поэтому туда list_of_numbers тоже нельзя вносить

```
def sequence(n):
    list_of_numbers=[]
    list_of_numbers.append(n)
    if n<=0:
        return list_of_numbers 
    return sequence(n-5)
```

Ответ например при print(sequence(16)):
[16, 11, 6, 1, -4]
При print(sequence(40)):
[40, 35, 30, 25, 20, 15, 10, 5, 0]

Comment: `sequence = lambda n: list(range(n, -5, -5))`

Comment: @EzikBro
спасибо, супер, кратко и верно

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему-то выходит None в конце. Вместо return писал print(), но ошибку выдает. (Python)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1374363/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82-none-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%86%d0%b5-%d0%92%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-return-%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bb-print-%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

список можно и не передавать, примерно так:

```
def sequence(n):
    return [n] if n<=0 else [n] + sequence(n-5)

sequence(16)  # [16, 11, 6, 1, -4]
```

Comment: Спасибо за код. Полностью удовлетворяет всем условиям задачи

Answer (score 5):

```
def sequence(n):
    if n[-1] <= 0:
        return n 
    n.append(n[-1]-5)
    return sequence(n)
print(sequence([21]))
```

#[21, 16, 11, 6, 1, -4]

Предлагаю передать сразу список и внутри его перекидывать до выполнения условия.

Comment: как же все просто оказывается) спасибо вам большое

Answer (score 3):

```py
def sequence(n, step: int = 5):
    return [*filter(lambda x: x + step >= 0, range(n, -step, -step))]

print(
    sequence(16)
)
# [16, 11, 6, 1, -4]
print(
    sequence(35)
)
# [35, 30, 25, 20, 15, 10, 5, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Где-то задание выдали такое? Только вчера отвечал на такой же вопрос, но искать его лень. Вы можете передавать ваш список при рекурсивном вызове функции. Только нужно специальным образом обработать самый первый вызов, лучше всего так:

```
def sequence(n, list_of_numbers=None):
    if list_of_numbers is None:
        list_of_numbers = []
    list_of_numbers.append(n)
    if n<=0:
        return list_of_numbers 
    return sequence(n-5, list_of_numbers)

print(sequence(16))
#[16, 11, 6, 1, -4]
print(sequence(40))
#[40, 35, 30, 25, 20, 15, 10, 5, 0]
```

Comment: Все отлично и ответы сходятся, но 1 условие задачи нарушается - должен быть один входной аргумент. За код спасибо